# MySQL server has gone away в php

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу с таким вопросом:
MySQL server has gone away 
Выводится каждый раз, когда я в вебсокет сервере запускаю вот этот кусок кода

```
$query = [];
        $query1 = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE active=2 AND hash_driver=""');
        
        while($row = $query1->fetch_assoc())
             $query[]= $row;


    foreach ($wsWorker->connections as $clientConnections){
        $clientConnections->send(json_encode($query));
    }
```

Я считаю, что это не дубликат, т.к таких ошибок в обычных запросах не встречал, а статей о том, что это происходит в вебсокете не нашел.
Все базовые ответы делал - не помогло
Прощу помощи, уже не знаю куда искать

Comment: таймаут соединения не бесконечный. пересоединяйтесь

Answer (score 0):

Проблема права заключалась в не резиновом таймауте, сделал в методе онмесседж подклбчение к бд и все прошло